# already use docker limit, why server cpu load average still high

Tags: docker, load

cpu:8

memory:64G

when use docker swarm to deploy application, already limit cpu and memory

```
docker service update java --reserved-cpu 2 --limit-cpu 2 --limit-memory 4G --reserve-memory 4G
```

use top to check server,

```
top - 11:09:26 up 889 days, 19:31, 16 users,  load average: 72.50, 78.28, 55.54
Tasks: 271 total,   2 running, 183 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 36.7 us,  7.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 52.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  3.7 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 65916324 total, 27546636 free,  8884904 used, 29484784 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used. 56442876 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
15566 root      20   0 12.563g 2.871g  17580 S 199.0  4.6  42:06.92 java
45076 root      20   0 19.018g 337692  16680 S 167.2  0.5   0:07.38 java
14692 root      20   0 1941688 122152  50868 S   4.0  0.2 617:42.71 dockerd
```

have not other application, why load average run so high
could someone help to check it，thx

Comment: Load average aside, this `top` output is consistent with what you've specified: the two `java` processes are each using less than 200% CPU and 4 GiB physical memory, and your 8-core system has 50% CPU idle cycles or 4 free cores.

Comment: yes, all seems ok  except load average,  so why load average so high, very strange